# Does the following piece of code lead to a deadlock?

Tags: operating-systems, synchronization, deadlocks, mutual-exclusion, critical-section

Process X

```
/* other code for process x*/
  while (true)  {
  1) varP = true;
  2) while (varQ == true)
     {
        /* Critical Section */
  3)    varP = false;
     }
}  
/* other code for process X */
```

Process Y

```
/* other code for process Y */
while (true)
{
  1) varQ = true;
  2) while (varP == true)
     {
        /* Critical Section */
  3)    varQ = false;
     }
}
/* other code for process Y */
```

For the above piece of code, it can be easily observed that Mutual exclusion isn't ensured i.e. both X and Y can access critical section at the same time. My doubt is regarding whether there exists a deadlock.

Consider the sequence of execution $X_1 Y_1 X_2 X_3 Y_2 Y_1 Y_2\cdots$ where X and Y represent the processes and the subscripts denote the numbered statements. Once the above sequence happens during the concurrent execution of $X$ and $Y$, $X$ stays stuck in its critical section and $Y$ never enters its critical section. Can this be viewed as a deadlock where the access to rest of the code of $X$ is denied by $Y$ and $Y$ is denied access to its CS by $X$?